# Get `perf` to provide alphabetized list of functions

Tags: perf

Despite providing `perf report` the `--sort symbol` option, it's always using the overhead as the primary sort key.

I'd like to get `perf` to provide me an alphabetized list of functions, with their overhead/measured ticks as the second column. Is this impossible without `perf script`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible (to be confirmed by perf experts) with `perf` directly. Nevertheless you can easily redirect `perf report` output to a file

```
perf report --stdio > out
```

Then remove the first "heading lines" prceeding the data and use `sort`:

```
sort -b -k 3 out
```